# Using custom sql in Django

Tags: django, datetime, time, timezone

Is there a way to run a custum SQL statement in Django? I have some timestamp fields in my database that have timezone information. Normally you could just enter the time in a format like: 2010-7-30 15:11:22 EDT and in my case postgresql will figure it out. But in Django it treats timestamps as Datetimes which don't store timezone information so I can't just update the model object with this string and save it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow must have missed the link in the documentation that covers this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly.